# Conditional button color attr in Angular Material (Components)

Tags: angular, angular-material, conditional-statements, angular-components

I have a component that takes an Input.. `@Input() coDeliveryCandidates: DeliverySlotView[];`

this is used in the template:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let coDeliverySlotView of (coDeliveryCandidates | async)">
  <button
    mat-raised-button
    [color]=""
  >
    {{ label  }}
  </button>
</ng-container>
```

color attribute takes a string as value and I would like to do something like:

```
[color]="{
  black: coDeliverySlotView.slotId === bookedSlot.slotId,
  grey: !coDeliverySlotView.slotId === bookedSlot.slotId
}"
```

Here I use the same syntax as ngClass but I guess it's not supported in that way.. so what other similar ways are there? :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Can just use the ternary operator

```
[color]="coDeliverySlotView.slotId === bookedSlot.slotId ? 'black' : 'grey'"
```

Comment:  angular material has some preset color like *primary,accent,warn* that why  'black' , 'gray' will not work ,you are correct in case this was a preset 

Answer (score 3):

```
<button mat-button [color]=" boolean_condition ? 'accent' : 'primary'">
```

This is a possible easy example using the color of material.

Comment: what if we have more then 2 condition, in my case I have 3 condition how will that look like??

Answer (score 1):

material design has built in three color called primary,accent,warn and base of the value you pass to color will set the need class , in this case the easy way to change the color is defined a class without set the color property

*style.scss*

```css
.black {
  &.mat-raised-button.mat-button-base {
    background: black ;
    color:#fff ;
  }
}

.gray {
  &.mat-raised-button.mat-button-base {
    background: #ccc ;
    color:#555 ;
  }
}
.orange {
  &.mat-raised-button.mat-button-base {
    background: orange ;
    color:#fff ;
  }
}
```

*template*

```html
<button mat-raised-button class="black">black</button>
<button mat-raised-button class="gray">gray</button>
<button mat-raised-button class="orange">orange</button>
```

set the class base of condition by ngClass directive and boolean property like this

```html
 <button mat-raised-button 
        [ngClass]="{'black': isBlack , 'gray' : !isBlack}" (click)="isBlack =!isBlack" >
        click to toggle
 </button>
```

[**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6jckpx)

Comment: We already have our own theme and the colors are present.. the question was simple about conditional...

Answer (score 0):

I used this method

**Component**

```
isActive = false;
```

**html**

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="isActive">    

<button mat-raised-button [color]="isActive ? 'warn' : 'warn'">
        {{isActive ? 'warn' : 'warn'}}
</button>
```